# Object vs String cloning and == operator

Tags: ruby, string, object, clone, equality

I don't understand why `clone` produces an `Object` that does not return `true` using the `==` operator, but `clone` on `String` does. Input appreciated.

```
obj = Object.new
copy = obj.clone
obj == copy # => false

a = "a string"
c = a.clone
a == c # => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the == operator on strings simply compares the values of the strings. For example
`"foo"=="foo" #=>true`

Objects, on the other hand, compare object id's unless otherwise told when using the == operator
`foo.new==foo.new #=>false` because the two objects won't have the same id's.

If you overloaded the Object's == operator you could have it be true as well, but by default it won't while the String class did override the == operator to compare the string's value. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I should have figured that out, especially since that's the default behavior in Java as well and Ruby seems to closely resemble Java in much of its OO behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of == operator is to compare the object_id of the two objects. When you create a new object with dup or clone the new object has a new object id.
Hence,

```
false, obj           == copy
```

But this behaviour of == can be overridden in inheriting classes. String overrides == to compare the value of the strings instead of the object_id. So when two strings have different object_id they can be equal because they have the same value.